# What is this brown catipillar with white stripes and two black spots near the head in Loveland, Colorado?

Tags: bug-identification, colorado, caterpillars

I was riding my bike today and I saw a number of these brown caterpillars with white strips and black spots near the head crossing the sidewalk. (Penny for scale)

[image]

Does anyone know what kind of caterpillar this is?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100%, but I am going to call that a yellow striped armyworm, [Spodoptera ornithogalli](https://www.iamgreenwise.com/armyworms-what-are-they-and-should-you-be-worried/).  These things seem to be widely distributed and very common; I've seen them frequently in my travels but never bothered to look it up until today.

Here's some additional, more close-up images for comparison:
[image]
[image]

Here's what it becomes as an adult:

[image]